# PHP idea about seat booking system?

Tags: php, html, css, session-variables

I have to make a simple bus seat reservation/booking system with **PHP** backend. Currently I have done the interface just by using html and css as you can see from the image below *(I selected 2 seats just for interface example)*:

[image: bus seat booking]

Ok, so the system is like user will choose their seat(s) like in the example, and then click submit button. After that it will show to the user the seat(s) that they have booked and total price. Then, when going back to the booking page, the seat(s) that are booked will show occupied and cannot be selected anymore.

I know it just a simple task, but I want to know the idea and the way on how I can assign the price for each seat, calculate the price, and most importantly to show the seat are reserved afterwards.

I don't need to use MySQL or anything related to database to store the information, just using **php session variable.**

Below is just my html code for reference.

```
<div class="bus">
  <form method="post">
  <ol class="bus_seat">
    <img src="img/steering.png" alt="driver" width="30" height="30" style="margin-left:8.45em; margin-top: 0.3em";>
    <li class="row row--1">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="Seat 1" id="1"/>
          <label for="1"></label>
        </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="Seat 2" id="2"/>
          <label for="2"></label>
        </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="3" id="3"/>
          <label for="3"></label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--2">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="4" id="4"/>
          <label for="4"></label>
        </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="5" id="5"/>
          <label for="5"></label>
        </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="6" id="6"/>
          <label for="6"></label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--3">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="7" id="7"/>
          <label for="7"></label>
        </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="8" id="8"/>
          <label for="8"></label>
        </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="9" id="9"/>
          <label for="9"></label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--4">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="10" id="10"/>
          <label for="10"></label>
        </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="11" id="11"/>
          <label for="11"></label>
        </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="12" id="12"/>
          <label for="12"></label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--5">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="13" id="13"/>
          <label for="13"></label>
        </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="14" id="14"/>
          <label for="14"></label>
        </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="15" id="15"/>
          <label for="15"></label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--6">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="16" id="16"/>
          <label for="16"></label>
        </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="17" id="17"/>
          <label for="17"></label>
        </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="18" id="18"/>
          <label for="18"></label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--7">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="19" id="19"/>
          <label for="19"></label>
        </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="20" id="20"/>
          <label for="20"></label>
        </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="21" id="21"/>
          <label for="21"></label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--8">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="22" id="22"/>
          <label for="22"></label>
        </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="23" id="23"/>
          <label for="23"></label>
        </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="24" id="24"/>
          <label for="24"></label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--9">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="25" id="25"/>
          <label for="25"></label>
        </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="26" id="26"/>
          <label for="26"></label>
        </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="27" id="27"/>
          <label for="27"></label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li class="row row--10">
      <ol class="seats" type="A">
        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="28" id="28"/>
          <label for="28"></label>
        </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="29" id="29"/>
          <label for="29"></label>
        </li>

        <li class="seat">
          <input type="checkbox" name="seatcheckbox[]" value="30" id="30"/>
          <label for="30"></label>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
  </ol>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: _"I don't need to use MySQL or anything related to database to store the information, just using php session variable."_ If you want to show these seats as no longer available, let alone work in any meaningful sense, you'll need a database.

Comment: @kmoser I am sorry to ask but cannot we just store the data just for that session using array in php?

Comment: Session information is not usually available to other processes. That means your system won't be able to show other users that certain seats are already taken.